# Как реализовать интерфейс для OpenGL приложения на Android?

Tags: android, opengl, gui, ui

На учебе, в рамках курса "Компьютерная графика", необходимо написать приложение на OpenGL. На свою беду (а может и нет) уговорил преподавателя разрешить писать под Android с использованием OpenGL ES. Собственно, с самой библиотекой проблем нет, вопрос в реализации интерфейса.

В первую очередь в голову приходит следующее: с помощью встроенной графики Android нарисовать на экране элементы UI поверх 3D сцены и отлавливать касания на них, это кажется не сложным, но вот уже отлавливать жесты масштабирования кажется не легким делом. Так как я могу ошибаться, или не знать про уже существующие решения, задаю вам этот вопрос.

Comment: А если бы не андроид, то какие действия надо поддерживать? Сделайте для начала обычные вещи, начало касания, движение, конец касания. Остальное потом по желанию допилите.